# Rows to columns using Pandas (Python)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have information **regarding yearly firm reports on a page level** (i.e., multiple pagewise information by report). Pagewise information is in separate rows, so that reports span over multiple rows covering pagewise information.

Correspondingly, my data looks as follows:

```
import pandas as pd

data = {
    'FIRM': ['A', 'A', 'B', 'B'],
    'YEAR': [2012, 2012, 2013, 2013],
    'Report Page': [1, 2, 1, 2],
    'Value1': [10, 15, 20, 25]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

**Resulting in the following dataframe:**

```
  FIRM  YEAR  Report Page  Value1
0    A  2012            1       10
1    A  2012            2       15
2    B  2013            1       20
3    B  2013            2       25
```

The **objective is to group the page-wise information on a report (i.e., year) level**. Hence, the intended output looks as follows:

```
  Firm  Year  Value1_Page1  Value1_Page2
0    A  2012            10            15
1    B  2013            20            25
```

As shown in the example, **page-wise information shall be maintained but transposed to a column level**, with adding the page number in column names (e.g., Value1_Page1). **Reports do not always have the same number of pages.** So far, I did not manage to come up with a meaningful attempt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with `pandas.pivot`:

```
df.pivot(index=['FIRM', 'YEAR'], columns='Report Page', values='Value1').add_prefix('Value1_Page').reset_index().rename_axis(None, axis=1)
df

             FIRM  YEAR  Value1_Page1  Value1_Page2
0              A  2012            10            15
1              B  2013            20            25
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Will accept as soon as I am allowed to!